# Getting DatabaseRefrence key of the RecyclerView if one of its item has been clicked

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, firebaseui

How can we get a database reference of a model class in Firebase RecyclerView if one of the item (say button) of recycler view is clicked?

Comment: Can you explain clearly?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48090067/recylerview-adapter-in-android-firebase-is-not-quite-syncing this one!

Comment: "Questions seeking debugging help ('why isn't this code working?') must include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and the shortest code necessary to reproduce it in the question itself. Questions without a clear problem statement are not useful to other readers. See: [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)."

Comment: Sir. I found the answer. Thanks for replying. Aren't you the same who teaches in Udacity ?